# How do I use the cursorMove command in an extension so that the cursor jumps to a specific position when clicking on a TreeItem element?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm currently trying to find a command that executes so that the cursor moves to a specific location I already have saved as a variable

My locations are saved like
`line = functions[i].location.range.start.line` for the specific line and `column = functions[i].location.range.start.character` for the specific position
I already know that I can kind of create the position with `new vscode.Position(line,column)`

Now, how exactly do I integrate this into the command
"`cursorMove({to: $ViewPosition, select: boolean, by: $By, value: number})`"?

The (default) thing that works for me to move the cursor up by one line, with

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand("cursorMove",{
     to: "up",
     by: "wrappedLine",
     select: false,
     value: 1
});
```

I want to implement my location/position from the functions array so that the command

```
let clickEvent = vscode.commands.registerCommand('homeItem.click', (functions[i].location) => {
    vscode.commands.executeCommand("cursorMove", {
        to: x,
        by: x,
        select: false,
        value: x
    });
});
```

sets the cursor focus to the provided position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options:

1. `cursorMove`'s are relative to the current position.  Not to an absolute position as I think you know.  So you would have to get the difference between the current cursor position `vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selection.active.line` and your `line = functions[i].location.range.start.line` and use that in the `cursorMove` command (after doing the math to know if you need up or down).

And you have to do the same for `character` and do a second `cursorMove` within the correct line to move by character if you care about that.  So it is a lot of work.

2. Just set the cursor position by setting a `selection`.

```js
const myPos = new vscode.Position(x,x);     // I think you know how to get the values, let us know if you don't
vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.selections = [new vscode.Selection(myPos, myPos)];
```

or do this check first:

```js
if (vscode.window.activeTextEditor) {
  const myPos = new vscode.Position(x,x);     // I think you know how to get the values, let us know if you don't
  vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.selections = [new vscode.Selection(myPos, myPos)];
}
```

Comment: the second is exactly what I searched for! Now I only don't know how to apply it correctly since when I try to add this into a registerCommand block I get
ts erro (2532): Object is possibly 'undefined'

Comment: nvm, I put a ! after activeTextEditor, so `vscode.window.activeTextEditor!.selections` fixes the problem and the cursor is put to the provided location, thank you!

Comment: I think you meant a `?` and not a `!` - I modified the3 answer with a couple of ways to handle that error warning.  Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you (click the green check mark).  Thanks.